# Python typing: Avoid `cast TypedDict` when filtering dict

Tags: python, casting, typing, typeddict

I have a `TypedDict` definition and want the typechecker to recognize that a certain dictionary, dynamically created by filtering another dictionary, is complying with the type definition:

```
from typing import cast, TypedDict


class Movie(TypedDict):
    name: str
    year: int


def expect_movie(movie: Movie):
    pass

data = {
    'name': 'Notting Hill', 
    'genre': 'romantic comedy', 
    'year': 1999,
}
movie = cast(Movie, {
    key: val for key, val in data.items()
    if key in Movie.__annotations__
})

expect_movie(movie)
```

Currently, the only way I found to get what I want is to use `cast`. Is there a way to avoid `cast`? Ideally,

```
movie = {
    key: val for key, val in data.items()
    if key in Movie.__annotations__
}
```

should work, but it gives me `Argument of type "dict[str, Unknown]" cannot be assigned to parameter "movie" of type "Movie" in function "expect_movie" "dict[str, Unknown]" is incompatible with "Movie"`.

Comment: The syntax for your dict comprehension is incorrect: `{k: v for key, val ...}`.

Comment: And you *should* be able to simply pass the dict directly to `Movie` rather than using `cast`, but `mypy` doesn't seem to like that (though the error message seems to be complaining that I'm not doing exactly what I am).

Comment: I think the problem is that the dict comprehension is too "dynamic"; the keys being added to `movie` are determined at runtime, since the type of `data` is just `dict[str,Any]` until the comprehension is evaluated.

Comment: @chepner I see. So we need to find another way of filtering the dictionary. Would a for loop over `Movie.__annotations__` do?

Comment: I think the problem is relying on `data.items()` to return the value seen in the `dict` literal. `mypy` isn't special-cased to know about the `dict` methods, so it only knows that `dict.items()` will return a sequence of tuples, without being able to infer *which* tuples from the static definition of `data`.

Comment: @chepner If you state in an answer that it is not possible without casting or explicitely instantiating `Movie`, together with a justification / explanation of the internal reasons, I'd accept it as answer and upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

Mypy's issue is the on-the-spot dict comprehension.

It is convinced by something like this:

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class Movie(TypedDict):
    name: str
    year: int


def dict_to_movie(d: dict) -> Movie:
    kwargs = {key: d[key] for key in Movie.__annotations__}
    return Movie(name=kwargs['name'], year=kwargs['year'])


def expect_movie(movie: Movie):
    pass


data = {
    'name': 'Nottingham Hill',
    'genre': 'romantic comedy',
    'year': 1999,
}

movie = dict_to_movie(data)

expect_movie(movie)
```

Comment: +1 as this technically answers the question. I hesitate to accept it as answer, though, becuse it looks very similar to using `cast`.

Comment: I think the bottom line is you'll need some sort of function to do the type coercion. Convincing mypy (or your IDE typechecker) that it works is just an added inconvenience.

Comment: If you're going to hardcode `name` and `year` in the call to `Movie`, there's no point creating `kwargs`. Just `return Movie(name=d['name'], year=d['year'])` is the same thing.